# Generate aab and apk

Tags: android-studio

When generating signed bundle or APK I need to choose one way or the other. But I wish to create both in single build, release settings for aab and debug for APK. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Bundle tool to generate `apk` from app bundle. [Download BundleTool](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases).

First, generate app bundle then use this bundle to convert it into `apk` by running below command

```
java -jar F:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\bundle-tools\bundletool-all-1.3.0.jar build-apks --bundle=F:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\bundle-tools\app-debug.aab --output=F:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\bundle-tools\app-debug.apks --mode=UNIVERSAL
```

Replace path to your file path of `bundle`, `bundletool` and output file path